# ajax form not finding javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, function

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong with this no matter how many things I try. I've looked through Google for a related issue but found nothing specific. Hopefully someone can help me.

The script runs through a external .js file calling a list of music albums, then listing the song of the album chosen via ajax. The user can then edit of delete the songs. Everything works fine until I submit the edited information through a form. When I click the submit button I get a web developer error "updateSong is not a function"

Here's the form:

```
    <?php
    include("database.php");

    $song =  $_GET['song'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM song INNER JOIN genre ON song.gID = genre.gID INNER JOIN album ON song.alID = album.alID WHERE sID = '$song'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo ("

    <form action='#' method='POST' name='updateSong' onSubmit='updateSong(\"$song\")'>
    <input name='songName' type='text' value='$row[songName]' />
    <input type='text' id='genreSearch' name='genre' alt='Genre Search' onkeyup='searchSuggest();' autocomplete='off' value='$row[genreName]'/>
    <div id='genre_search_suggest'></div>
    <input name='songURL' type='text' value='$row[songUrl]' />
    <input name='sID' type='hidden' value='$row[sID]' />
    <input name='Submit' type='Submit' value='Update Song' />
    </form>

    ");
    }

    ?>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
    function updateSong(sID) {
if(ajax) {
var song = sID;
alert("2");
ajax.open('get', './song_update.php' + encodeURIComponent(sID));
alert("3");
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
handleResponse(ajax);
}
ajax.send(null);
return false;

}
    }
```

//EDIT//
Here's the page it's loaded into. I removed the unnecessary stuff around what this question is dealing with.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="artistPageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/artistAjax.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="mediaPlayerBox">

    <div id="artistAlbumList">
    <?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `album` INNER JOIN artist ON album.aID = artist.aID WHERE artist.LoginKey = '$token'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo ("<div id='artistAlbumBox'><div id='artistAlbum'><a href='#' onclick='loadAlbum($row[alID])'><img src='$row[albumCover]' width='75px' height='75px' border='0px' ></a></div><div id='artistAlbumLabel'>$row[albumName]</div></div>");
 }
?>
</div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: are you getting any other javascript errors? it seems like your `updateSong()` function may have an error.

Comment: Don't `echo` HTML (hard to debug). Embed PHP into HTML.

Comment: Please show the entire page that is displaying the form.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show where the form is, post the entire js as well.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be: `onSubmit='updateSong("$song")'`?

Comment: It works without the quotes but I added them just to make sure and still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try doing onSubmit='return updateSong($song)'

Comment: Added it, still no luck though.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying it is not a function because it isn't loaded, are you loading the external script in the display page at all?

Comment: Yeah, its in the head of the document. There's two functions called prior to this one that work properly. The only difference is those first two are called via href links and this is via onSubmit.